# Find last nonzero element 3D array - numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find a way to perform this operation, i have an array of shape

[ batch_size , 150 , 1 ]

representing batch_size sequences of integers, each sequence is 150 elements long, but in each one there are a lot of zeros that were added in order to make all the sequences of the same length. I need to find the last nonzero element for each sequence, and put it in an array, the shape of this array has to be [ batch_size ] . I'd try the following :

```
last = []
for j in range(0 , inputs.shape[0] ):
  tnew = np.array( inputs[j][:][0] )
  tnew = np.trim_zeros(tnew )
   last.append( int(tnew[-1]) )
```

but I don't know if there is a better way to do this, with out having to loop over each element like that.

Thanks for your answers and help.

---

Test data

```
a = np.array([[[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
              [[1],[2],[0],[0],[0],[0]],
              [[1],[2],[3],[0],[0],[0]],
              [[1],[2],[3],[4],[0],[0]],
              [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[0]]])
```

Comment: You should always add some data that can be used to test - to make it easy for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
a.shape[1] - (a!=0)[:,::-1].argmax(1) - 1
```

Sample run -

```
In [191]: a = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,6,1))

In [192]: a
Out[192]: 
array([[[2],
        [1],
        [2],
        [2],
        [2],
        [0]],

       [[2],
        [1],
        [1],
        [0],
        [2],
        [0]],

       [[2],
        [1],
        [2],
        [0],
        [1],
        [1]]])

In [193]: a.shape[1] - (a!=0)[:,::-1].argmax(1) - 1
Out[193]: 
array([[4],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the quick answer. This give me the index right? for each element, how I can get the values from this indexes in a vectorized way. I need the values a[0,b[0],0]  a[ 1, b[1],0] and so on...

Comment: @RolandDeschain Use `a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],idx,0]`, where `idx` are the indices obtained from the posted solution.

Comment: Thanks! indexing drives me crazy jaja. Do you know some page or resource where I can learn a little more about complex numpy indexing ?.

Comment: @RolandDeschain This could be one stop - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing